# Storybook 4 and a webpack.config?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, storybook

So now with Storybook 4 out and it supports webpack 4, I am trying to figure where, how, and what is needed to integrate a `webpack.config` so I can add additional items  such as `webpackbar`. My setup, which first in my master was the setup a storybook and then add things around it for a project. That said, here is a screenshot of my folder structure and all including my `package.json`:

[image]

An

Comment: Has no one tried to upgrade with this to add your own config?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about storybook 4, but as per official storybook 5 documentation, you can pass your own custom webpack.config.js file, create this file inside .storybook folder.

> To effectively customise the webpack config, you might need to get the
>   full default config it's using.

https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/